# Java Selenium WebDriver Firefox how can i get boolean values from getStatus()?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im trying to make test in Eclipse, using Selenium and Firefox webdriver. I wrote next class:

```
public class Selenium {
    FirefoxDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setup(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    @Test
    public void go_to(String url){
        driver.get(url);
    }
```

Now in my main class im trying do that:

```
String url = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input where do you want to go");
        selenium.setup();
        report.start_report();
        selenium.go_to(url);
```

But also, i want to write

```
if(selenium.driver.getStatus)
```

Is there any command, to take boolean value, from my driver.get(url)? For example, if successful go to web page, then true, and if error, then false?

Comment: try/catch your driver.get call... set boolean to false if exception is thrown.

Comment: driver.getCurrentUrl() should return the current url which you could test for the correct url.

Comment: @arundeepchohan there can be redirect. Imagine navigating to https://www.cnb.cz, driver.getCurrentUrl() will return https://www.cnb.cz/cs/ or https://www.cnb.cz/en/.

Comment: Implicit wait should make it get the second one it would get the first one otherwise.